# Unpivot rows into columns

Tags: sql, unpivot

[image: Formatted Table Image- Click here]

I want to unpivot the a table, based on Case number: (see image for the formatted table)

However, it is a large dataset, so I cannot put the value of every date in the unpivot function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MYSQL does not have an unpivot function - do you want a mysql answer, a sqlserver answer or both?

Comment: Images of data isn't helpful to us. If you want to supply data, supply it as formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements. And, at the same time, fix your tags, SQL Server and MySQL are completely different RDBMS (I have removed the conflicting tags). You say you've "tried" as well; if you have please show us those attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `cross apply` for this:

```
select c.case_number, v.[date], v.status
from cases c cross apply
     (values (open, 'open'), (approved, 'approved')
     ) v([date], status)
order by c.case_number, v.[date];
```

Technically, `apply` implements a "lateral join".  This is a very powerful mechanism, and unpivoting is a good introduction to what they do.

By contrast, `unpivot` is bespoke syntax available in only a few databases.  It only does one thing -- and that one thing can just as easily be done in an other way.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/945a08/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Cases (CaseNumber int, OpenD date , Approved date )
insert into Cases(CaseNumber,OpenD,Approved)values(3527,'2/11/18','5/11/18')
insert into Cases(CaseNumber,OpenD,Approved)values(7756,'3/12/18','10/12/18')
insert into Cases(CaseNumber,OpenD,Approved)values(6192,'1/1/19',NULL)
```

**Query 1**:

```
Select CaseNumber,Date,Status
FROM Cases c
unpivot (
  Date for Status in (OpenD,Approved)
  ) as UnPVt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/945a08/1/0)**:

```
| CaseNumber |       Date |   Status |
|------------|------------|----------|
|       3527 | 2018-02-11 |    OpenD |
|       3527 | 2018-05-11 | Approved |
|       7756 | 2018-03-12 |    OpenD |
|       7756 | 2018-10-12 | Approved |
|       6192 | 2019-01-01 |    OpenD |
```